# Find basis to quotient space of 2 spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

My question is as follows:

V is the space of all n by n matrices.
W is a subset of V, and is defined by the space of all symmetric n by n matrices.

We are asked to find a basis for V/W

I don't know where to begin even, I don't understand this material very well and can use some help.

Comment: Start by answering these questions: What is the dimension of $V$? And what is the dimension of $W$?

Comment: The dimension of V is n squared, and the dimension of W is n*(n+1)/2

Comment: Next: What is the dimension of $V/W$? and can you find a basis for $V$?

Comment: the dimension of V/W is equal to n*(n-1)/2

Comment: basis for V, we could use the standard base

Comment: What is the dimension of the space of skew-symmetric matrices?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11093/discussion-between-oria-gruber-and-prahlad-vaidyanathan)

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $W'$ be the space of skew-symmetric matrices. Show that the map from $W' \to V/W$ given by
   $$
   A \mapsto \overline{A}
   $$
   is an isomorphism.
2. Now you need to find a basis for $W'$, so start with a basis for $V$, and note that any $A \in V$ can be written as
   $$
   A = \frac{A+A^t}{2} + \frac{A-A^t}{2} \in W + W'
   $$